# You check her forehead with your palm and her temperature is high. What do you say?

Tags: word-choice

Do you say "it burns", "it is burning", "it's hot", "she's burning", or "she's hot" when you notify another person about it?
I want to avoid to refer to the word "temperature".

Comment: Why avoid "temperature".  "She has a temperature" seems a very idiomatic expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could say *it's hot/burning* only if you had already mentioned her forehead, so that it was clear that *it* meant *her forehead*. Otherwise *she's hot/burning*.

I wouldn't use *burning* unless her temperature was **really** high.

The way I would almost always say this is *she's got a temperature*. That's the idiom in my (British) English.

Comment: In American English you would say *she's got a fever*

Answer (score 1):

If you are face to face with a sick person and you suspect she may have **a high temperature**, you can say

> **You're hot**
> You **feel** hot
> You've got a **fever**
> You're **burning** (when the person's distress is obvious even by looking.)

If you are reporting someone's high temperature then simply change the subject pronoun "you" to their preferred pronoun: "she", "he" or "they".

> **Her forehead** is very hot
> **He/she/they** must have a fever
> **She's feverish** (suggested by @Kate Bunting)

It is best to avoid using "it's hot/burning" unless you're referring to a sick animal or food that is currently being burnt.

Comment: How about when you notify another person? That's what I meant, I have updated the question.

Comment: @ABC change the subject pronoun to "she". She's got... She's hot etc.

Comment: "She's very feverish" if you must avoid 'temperature'.